# Qt Mobile MySQL development pattern

Tags: mysql, sql, qt, mobile

I want to create a mobile application using Qt Project. This application must get some data online from a remote MySQL database. So am I right to follow these steps?

1. Download Qt Windows for WP8, Qt Linux for Android and QT Mac for iOS.
2. Compile mysql plugin on these 3 platforms. (As example compile on Ubuntu for Android).
3. Code rest of the app and compile for targeted platform.
4. Finally, targeted platform requires MySQL driver, so how can I force the user to have MySQL driver on end user platform (android, ios, wp8)?

If there is a good solution for the problem, I'd like to hear them too. A web service...etc.